# Python loop not returning all lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm facing some issues to get all lines from the query that I'm running. The script below returns only the first line but I would like to get all lines from the query? What am I missing here?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
import cx_Oracle
import os
import json
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.disabled = True
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True

@app.route('/query')
def query1():

  connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='superuser', password='mypass1', dsn='moon.my-org.local:1521/db1_sql')
  cursor = connection.cursor()

  cursor.execute("""SELECT * from users""")

  for row in cursor:
      return str(row)

  cursor.close()
  connection.close()

port = int(os.getenv("PORT"))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

I also tried the change below, but no luck.

```
  content = []
  for row in cursor:
      content.append(row()[0])

  return str(content)

  cursor.close()
  connection.close()
```

Comment: `return` exits from the function so the loop stops.

Comment: `row` isn't a function, why are you using `row()`?

Comment: Nothing after `return` is executed. You need to do `cursor.close()` and `connection.close()` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the results with `cursor.fetchall()`

```
def query1():

  connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='superuser', password='mypass1', dsn='moon.my-org.local:1521/db1_sql')
  cursor = connection.cursor()

  cursor.execute("""SELECT * from users""")

  result = cursor.fetchall()

  cursor.close()
  connection.close()
  return result
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, and thanks for the tips. Only small change I've done was on the return line, adding str

  return str(result)

Before posting here, I tried to follow some docs on internet, and all return was inside of the loop, like this one https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pooling

Comment: Why would you want to convert a list to a string? How are you going to extract the data from it?

Comment: I don't see any returns inside loops in that doc. There's a loop with `print(result)` in it, that's not the same as return.